# how do i know what process using file on disk

Tags: resources, pid, monitor

when i launch resource monitor, in DISK section i see that specific file is being accessed (is in use)
[image]

now, how can i get that info from a command line?
Objective is not to delete the file from a directory, if it is in use (if resmon shows it in any way).

Challenge here is that an application writes some logs, but you can delete the log file, even if application is still running. Application just incrementally adds log entries into the same file. However if you delete that file, windows will allow you to do that, but application will stop writing logs, and i don't want to get that situation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not actual anymore
i am using **forfiles** command to detect logs that been intact for the last 7 days and archiving only them. 
it is easier and more clear than playing tricks with processes and other online metrics